# Word And TeX - can I copy and paste from one to the other?

Tags: support, editor, latex

Can I create a question on Stack Exchange in Microsoft Word and copy-and-paste it into the TeX box? What program creates ordinary math notation from TeX?

Comment: So you're interested in stripping the TeX from your question, and just post the output? Where do you want to post this content? I'm not sure *this* site is a good fit for you question.

Comment: If you want to create a Stack Exchange question other than in your browser, I strongly recommend using a plain text editor, not Word.

Answer (score 5):

The sites that offer LaTeX support will allow you to enter it in with special formatting blocks (someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `$...$` inline blocks are valid), and you'll get a convenient preview of it below.

**Most** sites don't offer LaTeX support, so you have to careful where you're asking and what you're asking.

If you're using something that offers mathematical symbols but *isn't* TeX, then you have two options:

- If it's a site that supports it, convert it to TeX.
- If it's not, take a relatively well-sized screenshot of it to get your point across.